# Calculate exact sleep time inside loop

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to calculate exact loop time in ascending order for a loop.

Here is what i have tried...

```
$tasks = array(
    array(
        'halt' => 5,
        'task' => 'first'
    ),
    array(
        'halt' => 10,
        'task' => 'second'
    ),
    array(
        'halt' => 15,
        'task' => 'third'
    ),
);

$halt_time = 0;
foreach($tasks as $task){
    $halt_time = $halt_time > 0 ? $task['halt'] - $halt_time : $halt_time + $task['halt'];
    if ($halt_time > 0) sleep($halt_time);
}
```

This works, it runs loop according to correct time, but gets failed when halt time is same for example, it won't work correct for following array...

```
$tasks = array(
    array(
        'halt' => 5,
        'task' => 'first'
    ),
    array(
        'halt' => 5,
        'task' => 'second'
    ),
    array(
        'halt' => 5,
        'task' => 'third'
    ),
);
```

In this case, it should only wait 5 seconds before first task and then run each task.

I want to explain - It shouldn't sleep for 15 seconds in second task if it already slept for 5 seconds in previous task, so - `sleep(5)` for first task, and `sleep(10)` for second task.

What's am i missing in calculation formula. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Explicitly check when `$halt_time` is 0?

Comment: @u_mulder I don't understand, can you please explain?

Comment: `$halt_time = (($task['halt'] > 0) &&  ($task['halt'] > $halt_time)) ? $task['halt'] :$task['halt'] - $halt_time; `

Comment: @Anant This doesn't solve the purpose.

Comment: I want to explain - It shouldn't sleep for 15 seconds in second task if it already slept for 5 seconds in previous task, so - `sleep(5)` for first task, and `sleep(10)` for second task.

Comment: Why not just use `halt` time directly? i.e. $task['halt']. The order of running is decided by the array order.

Comment: @RyanVincent This won't work on correct time then. Check my edited question.

Comment: You want to delay the difference _if the delay for the current task is greater than the total time so far_: i.e. sleep time is current - total (is positive) Otherwise use the current time as the delay. Always add the sleep time to the current total.

Comment: @RyanVincent can you post this as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you just count the seconds you waited and then check this value too. Short but untested code.

```
$halt_time       = 0;
$total_wait_time = 0;
foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    print_r(sprintf("starting %6s task at %s", $task['task'], date("H:i:s")));
    $halt_time = $task['halt'];
    if ($total_wait_time <= $halt_time) {
        $halt_time = $halt_time - $total_wait_time;
    }

    if ($halt_time > 0 || $total_wait_time === 0) {
        sleep($halt_time);
        $total_wait_time += $halt_time;
    }
    print_r(sprintf(", finished at %s\n", date("H:i:s")));
}
```

For first array the output is:

```
starting  first task at 19:29:28, finished at 19:29:33
starting second task at 19:29:33, finished at 19:29:38
starting  third task at 19:29:38, finished at 19:29:43
```

For the second one:

```
starting  first task at 19:30:58, finished at 19:31:03
starting second task at 19:31:03, finished at 19:31:03
starting  third task at 19:31:03, finished at 19:31:03
```

Hope that's what you need, if not I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Its working fine for second array but not first array.

Comment: This works good for second array but when i tested this with first array it only sleeps for first task and then run each task same time. `5, 10, 15 returns 12:50:05, 12:50:05, 12:50:05`

Comment: Sorry for late answer update. I rewrote my code and tested it based on your comments. Hope thats what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

All code is untested. ;-/

This is about two separate uses of the 'halt' (`$delayHalt`) value:

1) It can be a 'total cumulative time to wait' i.e. if it is greater than the total execution time so far (`$delayTotal`), then delay so that the total so far is the `$delayHalt` time.

2) It can be a time to delay this task for.

How do we identify them?

- We keep a running total of delays so far ($delayTotal)
- We check the 'current Halt (`$delayHalt`) value:

If it is greater than the `$delayTotal` then:

- `$delaySleep = - $delayHalt - $delayTotal`;

Otherwise we treat it as a delay to sleep for:

- `$delaySleep = $delayHalt`

We always add `$delaySleep` to`$delayTotal`.

We then sleep($delaySleep);

It should do what is required.

Example code:

```
$delayTotal = 0;

$delayHalt  = 0;
$delaySleep = 0;

$halt_time = 0;

foreach($tasks as $task){
    print_r(date('H:i:s')); 

    $delayHalt = $task['halt'];

    $delaySleep = $delayHalt; // default

    if ($delayHalt > $delayTotal) { // calculate difference
        $delaySleep = $delayHalt - $delayTotal ;
    }

    $delayTotal += $delaySleep; // total nap time

    sleep($delaySleep); // snooze
    print_r(date('H:i:s'));   
}
```